# How to write attribute name on two lines in a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I write heading column names in two lines in a *SQL* query?

I want it to display like this:

- column
  name

Comment: post more information

Comment: More information please. This is very confusing.

Comment: i want column name in in two lines like e.g i have column name slot name it should be like slot in first line name in next lines but it should be heading of column

Comment: does not make sense until you explain problem properly

Comment: It might be done in your application programming, not in sql

Comment: I made your question more clear, just waiting on the peer review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When naming a column in a simple `SELECT` statement like so:

```
SELECT stuff FROM someTable
```

Which will print out like so:

### ----stuff----

### --    foo

### --    bar

You can name the column *stuff* to whatever you like by using single quotations and the `AS` alias identifier, 
like so:

```
SELECT stuff AS 'Stuff Column' FROM someTable
```

This will print out like:

### ----Stuff Column----

### --    foo

### --    bar

To place the name on two lines you can try a pipe: | this will work with some *IDE*'s like so:

```
SELECT stuff AS 'Stuff|Column' FROM someTable
```

Query would look like this:

### ----Stuff

### ----Column

### --    foo

### --    bar

Read more on using aliases [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) or formatting columns [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a82950/ch4.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The method for splitting a column title to multiple lines varies with the SQL version you are using.

If the following doesn't work for you (suggested by @Darrell)

```
SELECT stuff AS 'Stuff|Column' FROM someTable
```

Then try

```
SELECT stuff AS 'Stuff\nColumn' FROM someTable
```